# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpcap in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans, jpcap

i am using netbeans ide and trying to capture packets using jpcap library. my program used to run correctly before bu suddenly this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpcap in java.library.path
```

is appearing. i have tried ds on my other computer too but in vain ..
i have added jpcap library and before installing i cleared older version completely. have done everythng available .i am seriously in trouble

please help!

Answer (score 7):

Add this to the beginning of your program:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

You should get a list of directories. Your `jpcap`'s `DLL` (or `so` on UNIX) must be in one of these directories in order for your program to work. If it is not there, then either:

- Add the directory containing that `DLL`/`so` to your system's `PATH` (preferred).
- Add the `DLL`/`so` into one of the directories printed.