# How to install jpcap for Centos?

Tags: java, centos, installation, jpcap

I'm very new to Centos. I tried to install extracted jpcap from jpcap-0.7-1.i386.rpm and capture packets, but I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpcap in
>   java.library.path     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   jpcap.JpcapCaptor.(JpcapCaptor.java:251)  at
>   trial01.SnifferAgent.main(SnifferAgent.java:185)
>   /root/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned:
>   1

Comment: [Updating $PATH variable](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3083).

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806199/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-jpcap-in-java-libr.